# True or False: Every bounded set of reals consisting of isolated points is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have to prove or disprove the following:

> **Theorem 1?** Every bounded set of reals consisting of isolated points is finite.

My intuition is that it is **false**, since the problem set continues with a stronger statement:

> **Theorem 2?** Every compact set of reals consisting of isolated points is finite.

A possible counterexample to **Theorem 1** would be the bounded set $S=\left\{ \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \right\}$. Since every point in $S$ can be contained within an open set (under the standard topology of $\mathbb R$) which intersects no other points of $S$.

However, the contrapositive of the $\mathbb R$-version of **Bolzano-Weierstrass** is:
$$
\text{Let $S\subseteq \mathbb R$. If $S$ has no accumulation points, then either $S$ is unbounded or finite.}
$$

Thus $-$ in line with **Theorem 1**'s assumption $-$ let $S \subseteq \mathbb R$, such that $S$ is bounded and consists exclusively of isolated points. Since a point is an isolated point **iff** it is not an accumulation point, we use **Bolzano-Weierstrass** to deduce that $S$ is either *unbounded* or *finite*. But, by assumption, $S$ is *bounded*, so by a simple disjunctive syllogism, it must be that $S$ is finite, thus "proving???" **Theorem 1**.

Where is the mistake? Is my statement of **Bolzano-Weierstrass** wrong? Is the counterexample to **Theorem 1** incorrect?

Comment: Are the points of $\{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ isolated?

Comment: I would think so, right? Since we can look at every point of $\{1/n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and its adjacent neighbors. There certainly are non-zero distances between $\frac{1}{n-1}$ , $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're interpreting the accumulation points in your contrapositive of Bolzano-Weierstrass as *accumulation points in $S$* as opposed to *accumulation points in $\mathbb{R}$*. And yes the points $\frac{1}{n}$ are isolated from each other.

Comment: So you have your hands on an infinite set of isolated points in $\mathbb{R}$.  Huzzah!  As @BrunoB points out, the problem here is that the set $S = \{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not contain any accumulation points.  As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ it *has* an accumulation point, but that point is not in $S$.

Comment: Oh my bad, ${0}$ is an accumulation point of $\{1/n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. Thus **Bolzano-Weierstrass** is not applicable.

Comment: There are cases like (maybe not your level yet?) the identity theorem for holomorphic functions where you do look at accumulation points in the subset itself, so it is somewhat of a good distinction to have in mind, but in the case of Bolzano-Weierstrass you do care about overall accumulation points and not just the ones residing in the subset.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Nice, now I can prove **Theorem 2**. Since the $S$ should be closed, it contains its accumulator, and I can apply **Bolzano-Weierstrass** to show that it is finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already said the gist of it in the comments, but just so there is an actual answer:

The problem here was that you were interpreting the accumulation points in your contrapositive of Bolzano-Weierstrass as *accumulation points in $S$*
as opposed to *accumulation points in $\mathbb{R}$*. The difference can feel subtle but it exists nonetheless, and the notion of accumulation points in the subset itself is used in, for example, the identity theorem for holomorphic functions (which may or may not be something you've seen or are going to see for now, but that's the first example that comes to mind), thus the two concepts do coexist.

In the context of Bolzano-Weierstrass, the theorem says (once rephrased with sets like you've done) that for a countable bounded set $S$, $S$ has at least one accumulation point *in $\mathbb{R}$*: if it were "*in $S$*", then your example $S := \left\{\frac1n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}^*\right\}$ ($\mathbb{N}^*$ means $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ for us French) would disprove Bolzano-Weierstrass since its only overall accumulation point is $0 \notin S$, and generally it's never a good sign when you go against a well-established theorem... :^)

Note that technically the exact contrapositive of the usual statement of Bolzano-Weierstrass would have the conclusion "uncountable" alongside the options "unbounded" and "finite" but you've probably noticed yourself - or whatever material you used might have made you noticed with some remark or corollary - that if $S$ is bounded uncountable then taking a countable sequence does the trick to find an accumulation point, of course. Anyway, I'm just rambling at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It is false. Choose in the interval $(0,1)$ an infinite set of rational $\{r_n \}$ and for each of them consider the sequence $S_{n,m}=\left\{r_n+\dfrac{r_n}{m}\right\}_{m\in \mathbb N}$. Each of these sequences is bounded because $S_{n,m}$ tends to $r_n$ when $m$ tends to infinity. Now the union of the first thousand terms (the number $1000$ is arbitrary) for all the $n$
$$ \left\{r_n+\dfrac{r_n}{1},r_n+\dfrac{r_n}{2},r_n+\dfrac{r_n}{3},\cdots,r_n+\dfrac{r_n}{1000}\right\}_ {n\in\mathbb N}$$ is an infinite bounded set of isolated points.